# Wordpress show parent pages in adminmenu

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type that is hierarchical, basically my list of pages within this type looks like:

```
page 1
- subpage 1
- subpage 2
page 2
- subpage1
- subpage2
...
```

I would like to show page1 and page2 (all the level 0 pages) in the drop down in the admin menu. And when one of those is clicked I would like to list only its children. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Try that plugin for your needs https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/ it much easy to edit than change it in code

Comment: I rather not use a plugin, is it possible without?

Comment: Follow the example here https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-wordpress-admin-pages/ Do you need to show the subpage dynamically or it will be static?

Comment: post on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/